# Integrating github's public keys API with ssh

Tags: linux, macos, ssh, github

**Hi**, i'm wondering if this is possible and safe, to have my `http://github.com/{username}.keys` as the default **authorized_keys** file for my private dev server.
So that if I add a new key to github - usually when you install a new OS or get a new machine, you would instantly be able to ssh into your remote machine, thoughts?

**Related:**

- http://developer.github.com/v3/users/keys/
- http://thechangelog.com/github-exposes-public-ssh-keys-for-its-users/

Answer (score 2):

It's *safe* in the sense that it is always safe to share your public keys.

However, it is generally *not recommended* to use the same key for multiple services. Simply due to the fact that if someone, by whatever means, gains access to your matching private key, he will have access to *any* of the services you used it for.

Comment: thanks for the answer, do you think it is a good idea to have those keys from github as a "live" authorized_keys to login for my *private* server(not production)?

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't do it. Simply because some keys have access to my GitHub account which I would never ever want to let have access to user accounts of mine on other systems. I like GitHub, but I would never let them control which keys have access to my *servers*, which would essentially be what you're doing.